# Create multiple Excel Spreadsheets

Tags: excel, vb.net

I am trying to create multiple spreadsheets in a single Excel file and I get the following error:

> Public member 'workbook' on type 'Application class

This is my code:

```
Private Sub MakeExcelWorksheets_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MakeExcelWorksheets.Click
    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
    xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Dim newWorksheet As Excel.Worksheet

    Try
        newWorksheet = CType(xlApp.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(), Excel.Worksheet)

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        Exit Sub
    End Try

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that *Workbook* (in your code: ... = CType(xlApp.Workbook. ... ) is not a property of the Excel application object. That is why you get the exception:

*"Public member 'Workbook' on type 'ApplicationClass' not found."*

Try this...

```
    Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop
    Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction

     Private Sub MakeExcelWorksheets_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MakeExcelWorksheets.Click
        Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
        xlApp = DirectCast(CreateObject("Excel.Application"), Excel.Application)
        Dim newWorksheet As Excel.Worksheet
        Dim newWorkBook As Excel.Workbook

        Try
            'newWorksheet = CType(xlApp.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(), Excel.Worksheet)
            If xlApp.Workbooks.Count > 0 Then
                newWorkBook = DirectCast(xlApp.Workbooks(1), Excel.Workbook)
            Else
                newWorkBook = DirectCast(xlApp.Workbooks.Add(), Excel.Workbook)
            End If
            newWorksheet = DirectCast(newWorkBook.Sheets.Add(), Excel.Worksheet)

        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
            Exit Sub
        End Try

    End Sub
```

You might not need the logic to add a new workbook when none exists if you're guaranteed that your Excel application object will definitely have at least one workbook.

This should resolve the exception you reported and produce a new instantiated 'Worksheet' object in the Excel workbook.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add multiple `Sheets` to your Excel `Workbook` this is the code to do that:

```
Dim app As New Excel.Application
Dim wb As Excel.Workbook = app.Workbooks.Add()
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet

ws = CType(wb.Sheets.Add(Count:=10), Excel.Worksheet)
```

By default a `Workbook` comes with one `Sheet`. If you want to add more than one set the `Count:=` parameter. As you can see in my example I have used **10**. This will leave me with 11 `Sheets` to work with.

> Note that `ws` will now be the last sheet in the `Workbook`. In my example this would be **Sheet11**.

If you want to work with each `Worksheet` then you would need to look at the following code:

```
Dim ws1 As Excel.Worksheet = CType(wb.Sheets(1), Excel.Worksheet)
Dim ws2 As Excel.Worksheet = CType(wb.Sheets.Add(), Excel.Worksheet)
```

> Note that `ws1` references to the first sheet. As said above a `Workbook` by default comes with one sheet.

Slight note. You don't need `xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")`. Instead use `Dim xlApp As New Excel.Application` since you are already working with the `Excel` objects.